# How do you "set the SelectedIndex property of the list box to display the appropriate name"?

Tags: vb.net, selectedindex

I'll be more specific. The goal of this is in (Visual Basic) to create a list box with all 50 US states, I am to made a text box with a "TextChanged" action that when the user types in the first couple letters of a state name, it shows that particular state. (For example, typing "Fl" might show Florida). I'm aware of what the SelectedIndex property is, but not really sure how to correctly use it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a standard `ComboBox`, you can set

- `AutoCompleteMode = Append`
- `AutoCompleteSource = ListItems`

And make sure you `DataSource` is set to the list of states. For example, given this code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
  With dict
    .Add("FL", "Florida")
    .Add("NY", "New York")
    .Add("AK", "Alaska")
  End With
  With ComboBox1
    .ValueMember = "Key"
    .DisplayMember = "Value"
    .DataSource = dict.ToList
  End With
End Sub
```

If you type `N` in the ComboBox, it will suggest `New York` and this code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  MsgBox(ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
End Sub
```

Will return `NY`.